# How to get the maximum values in one column for each value of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the items having max `value` per `ITEM` in following table:

**Input table:**

```
value | ITEM
1     | A 
2     | B
3     | C
4     | A
5     | B 
6     | C
7     | E
```

**Wanted result:**

```
value | ITEM
4     | A
5     | B 
6     | C
7     | E
```

Comment: Is `7` or `E` the expected value? Or both?

Comment: google aggrigate [functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Item, Value, MaxValue = (SELECT MAX(t2.VALUE)
                                FROM TableName t2
                                WHERE t.Item= t2.Item)
FROM TableName t
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/026f8/1/0)

or, if you don't want all records, use `Group By`:

```
SELECT Item, MaxValue = MAX(VALUE)
FROM TableName t
GROUP BY Item
```

[**SQL-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/026f8/2/0)

Comment: first part of your answer is slow and should be solved with the syntax: SELECT ITEM, Value, max(value) over (partition by item) maxvalue FROM tablename

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: imho that is too general. With proper indexes the sub-query can even perform faster than the `Over`-clause. I've tested it only just on a medium table(20M rows) where the sub-query came immediately   whereas the `max(value) over (partition by item)` took a few seconds because of a semi optimal execution plan. However, i'm using SQL-Server 2005, maybe it works better now.

Comment: Tim - I can confirm your claim in sqlserver 2008. I am speechless. The subselect version was 3 times faster than the over-clause in my test. I tested on 1 mil rows

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
select MAX(value ) as MAXvalue , ITEM from tbl_name 
group By ITEM
```